# how does serverless invoke in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless

I am new to this whole serverless framework.  I created my first serverless function as documented here https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless#quick-start.  Next when I do a "serverless invoke" it works.  I am confused how this works, the questions I have around this are

1. There does not seem to be an API gateway created so how can it invoke?
2. There are also stages mentioned in the serverless.yml file, I'm not sure what these translate to

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the default code comes with the AWS template, is only having a Lambda function declared. Let me try to answer your questions inline.

> There does not seem to be an API gateway created so how can it invoke?

Yes, since there is no API Gateway created, its not possible to invoke the Lambda through URLs. However, it is possible to invoke the Lambda using AWS CLI or SDKs which is what Serverless Framework is providing with "serverless invoke". To create a API Gateway, you need to add an event object to the function code as shown below.

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: hello
```

> There are also stages mentioned in the serverless.yml file, I'm not
>   sure what these translate to

When you define a stage in serverless.yml file, after the deployment, it creates a stage in API Gateway including it in the API Gateway URL path as shown below.

```
https://your-api/<stage-you-defined>/resurce-methods
```

*Note: that if you setup a custom certificate for API Gateway, then you have option to setup your own custom paths.*

Also its important to note that, although API Gateway supported this feature to have different stages(e.g test, staging, production) of a Single API Gateway deployment, latest Serverless Framework doesn't use this feature. Instead when you define a new stages, it will deploy a whole new API Gateway with the new stage. Serverless Framework has the argument for separating the API Gateway and having a single stage to self-contain each stage for isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an API gateway for invoking your lambda

Or

You can get event driven. Where your lambda gets invoked in response to some events like a new message in AWS SNS or when a new object gets created in S3

Or

You can have scheduled invocations using cloudwatch trigger events

For a comprehensive list of events that can invoke lambda see [Invoking Lambda Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html)

Comment: thanks, however I wanted to know how Serverless invoke worked, since it does not seem to be creating anything ( I am new to AWS so I could very easily be missing something)

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#lambda_region) there are HTTPS endpoints for Lambda.  For example, in the `us-east-1` region the endpoint is `https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.  This is how you're able to call a Lambda directly without the API gateway.  API gateway can add additional functionality and puts a full HTTP protocol on top of a Lambda.